# QAM signal equation

Tags: signal, qam

I have seen that QAM signal equation is written as sum or substraction between in-phase and quadrature component.

Does it really matters if we write QAM signal equation with + or - sign? It depends whether we use $$\cos(a+b)=\cos a\cos b-\sin a\sin b$$ or $$\cos(a-b)=\cos a\cos b+\sin a\sin b$$ to derive the basic equation if we have a carrier$$A\cos(2\pi f_ct+\phi)$$. The final result depends whether we used phase of +90 or -90 degrees:

(1)
$$S(t)=Icos(2\pi f_ct)-Qsin(2\pi f_ct)$$

(2)
$$S(t)=Icos(2\pi f_ct)+Qsin(2\pi f_ct)$$

Is it correct to use both if these equations? My guess is yes because it's basically the same result and only matters using components that are +90 or -90 degrees shifted with respect to carrier.

I am not electrical engineer.

Comment: What is a "QAM signal equation"? I'm working in digital comms, and I'm absolutely not sure what you're referring to, and you should very likely just add that formula to your question. There's different formulas which you might be referring to, describing a signal, but the fact that you call it *equation* might hint to you meaning something that isn't obvious from the start. (I'm voting to close this as unclear, but will happily retract the vote as soon as you edit your question and clarify which equation you're referring to).

Comment: Oh, and @Polynomial: If you add TeX `$$`, please also be sure to correctly `\\` things like \$\cos\$, otherwise they'll be indistinguishable from \$c\cdot o \cdot s\$

Comment: @MarcusMüller The TeX was already added by OP, I just corrected the surrounding dollar signs so that it displayed. I didn't notice the missing backslash!

Comment: Here's one example with subtraction: http://www.radio-electronics.com/info/rf-technology-design/quadrature-amplitude-modulation-qam/theory-equations.php . Another example with summation of I and Q component https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Communication_Systems/Quadrature_Amplitude_Modulation

Comment: @Navi Sorry, you still haven't pointed out which formula you're *actually* referring to. We will not *guess* what you mean with "QAM signal equation". You **must** include that crucial info *in your question itself*, not on a site that you link to from a comment without even so much as pointing out what formula from these two pages you're actually referring to. (and, seriously, it can't be that hard to actually include the formula you ask about in your question!)

Comment: @Marcus Müller I have edited my original question. Hopefully, It will be much clearer. I apologize for slopiness.

Comment: What are a and b?

Comment: @Andy aka a and b represent angles in trigonometric functions of sum and difference of two angles.

Comment: so, what do \$a\$ and \$b\$ have to do with your question?

Comment: I forgot to edit that part. In order to transform the carrier I have used these identities.

Comment: Leave this question open, its been fixed

Answer (score 1):

As Dave answered, if you flip the sign will be incomprehensible by receiver. Look the constellation.

[image: 16-QAM Constellation]

Using flipped sign for Q, instead of "1101" you will get "1111" by constellation, for example.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Please see my comment on Dave's answer.

Comment: I need 50 rep to comment another post. What you means with I+Q? Did you see the demodulation block diagram? In the diagram use a mixer in phase and quadrature, after thar a Low pass filter. Flip sign you will get "-Q/2" after the LPF for quadrature.

Comment: About the "Q/2", to "fix" this division by 2, you multiply the demodulator oscillator by 2. 2cos(2*pi*fc*t)....

Comment: I mean that S(t) can be expressed as (1) difference or (2) summation of in-phase and quadrature component in order to generate QAM signal, as long it is used only (1) OR (2) at both sides -sender and receiver end?

Comment: Mathematically yes, you can. But to implement the circuit or code to do this isn't easy, you will need synchronize the quadrature perfectly and do + or -, if not will get Vestigial spectrum of modulated or another things sometimes.

Comment: Think: S1= Icos(x1)+Qsin(x1), S2= Icos(x2)+Qsin(x2). When make S1-S2 or S1+S2, even x1 is near of x2, will result a small error. If not synchronized the error will be larger.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course it matters.  Flipping the sign of one component of the QAM signal produces a mirror-image constellation that will be incomprehensible to a receiver.

If you also flip the sign at the receiver, you get an equivalent system that is incompatible with the original.

Comment: Why it is somewhere written as summation of I and Q component?

Comment: It's an arbitrary choice. As I said, it leads to equivalent, but incompatible systems.

Comment: I didn't mean it is the same to use both equation at the same time, but only one equation. E.g. it is correct to use I+Q as long it is the same on sender and receiver side.

Answer (score 0):

The proper convention is the one with the minus sign. This stems from the use of *baseband equivalent* or *complex envelope* techniques to describe quadrature modulation. This is more general than just QAM.

A complex baseband signal \$s(t)\$ can be written in rectangular form \$s(t)=i(t)+jq(t)\$ with \$i(t)\$ the *in-phase* and \$q(t)\$ the *quadrature* component of the signal.

To obtain the (real-valued) passband signal \$s_p(t)\$ from the complex baseband signal \$s(t)\$, use
$$
s_p(t) = \Re\{s(t) \cdot \exp(j2\pi f_c t)\} = \Re\{(i(t)+jq(t)) \cdot \exp(j2\pi f_c t)\} = i(t) \cdot \cos(2\pi f_c t) - q(t) \cdot \sin(2\pi f_c t).
$$